# Why is there a wire through the top ears of a clock outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I found an outlet hidden behind a clock, and the way someone mounted it is baffling.

[image]

Why would someone do this, and what is the best way to undo it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons for the hack.

1. The top screw holding the receptacle to the electrical box stripped out.
2. They used the brilliant scheme as a way to provide a hook to hang the clock.

I have to guess that there was also no cover plate on this outlet behind the clock.

To undo this will require a number of steps.

1. First off shut off power at the breaker/fuse panel for this circuit.
2. Use a needle nose pliers to bend and twist the top side loops till they break off the screw tab on the outlet. These normally come off easily as they are pre-scored.
3. Remove the two straight slotted screws that hold the outlet in place.
4. Pull the outlet out away from the wall. (This step to help prevent the brittle looking outlet from getting broken).
5. Use a hammer, pry bar and/or pliers to hold and work the staple down out of the wall.
6. Now evaluate the outlet. Now would be a good time to replace it if the bakelite/plastic looks brittle or if the contacts do not hold a plug securely. New ones are low cost.
7. Push the outlet back into position.
8. Reinstall the two retaining screws.
9. Apply spackle to patch the holes where the staple went into the wall.
10. Patch paint the area above the outlet when the spackle has dried.
11. Install a new cover plate over the outlet.
12. Turn the power back on at the breaker/fuse panel.
13. Rehang the clock if it is a treasured antique heirloom.

Comment: I think you're onto something with #2, but I'm not clear on the long "undo" proposal. It looks to me like a simple bent wire through the outlet ears.

Comment: You're correct on no cover plate. However, it was not used as the clock mount. The hole in the wall right above the outlet was the clock mount. The clock in question was like a dollar store clock... Battery powered no less.

Comment: While I think this is probably the best answer I'm going to get, I think I'm going to go a different direction and just rip the whole thing out and seal up the wall. It's not in a useful location.

Comment: The Dollar Store clock may have been placed there in more recent times. There was a time in decades gone by when AC powered wall clocks were found in nearly all houses that were wired into the power grid. It was so common that there were even special electrical outlets that had their face recessed into the wall about 1 inches so that a plug from the clock would not stick out from the wall surface. The wire loop gag may have been crafted for a clock that long ago gave up the ghost.

Comment: You forgot to mention that wall clock outlets were specifically made with [little hooks](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51eDta3Vc5L._SL1276_.jpg) to hang the clock on.  I'm sure that's what the wire was for before the dollar store clock was installed.